# Eliminating range key criteria for Dynamo Update query?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How can I get Dynamo's UpdateItemRequest to either ignore the range key, or do a coarse test such as not null?

I am using a range key which contains the time of a record update.  Separately, I update rows which I select using an ID field which is not a key.  I update the ID field using an expectedAttribute in an UpdateItemRequest.  Dynamo's UpdateItemRequest forces me to specify a range key value. My ID update code will not know the range key value.  Can I somehow not specify a range key and not get an error? Or can I provide a simple range key test like not null?

When I remove the range key, AWS throws an error, "The provided key element does not match the schema"

```
//  construct the update map 
                    HashMap<String, AttributeValueUpdate> updates = new HashMap<String, AttributeValueUpdate>();

                    AttributeValue av = new AttributeValue().withN("1");

                    AttributeValueUpdate avu = new AttributeValueUpdate().withValue(av).withAction(AttributeAction.PUT);

                    updates.put("Column1", avu);

                    AttributeValue av2 = new AttributeValue().withN("2");

                    AttributeValueUpdate avu2 = new AttributeValueUpdate().withValue(av2).withAction(
                            AttributeAction.PUT);

                    updates.put("Column2", avu2);

                    // construct the key map 
                    HashMap<String, AttributeValue> keyMap = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();

                    AttributeValue hashValue = new AttributeValue().withN("10");
                    keyMap.put("hashKey", hashValue);

                    AttributeValue lastModKeyValue = new AttributeValue().withN("1404175127074");

                    // ****** I want to remove this key but Dynamo throws an error
                    keyMap.put("problemRangeKey", lastModKeyValue);

                    //  expected value comparison 
                    AttributeValue idValue = new AttributeValue().withN("100");

                    ExpectedAttributeValue expected = new ExpectedAttributeValue(idValue);

                    UpdateItemRequest request = new UpdateItemRequest().withTableName(DatabaseConstants.CHART_TABLE)
                            .withKey(keyMap).withAttributeUpdates(updates).addExpectedEntry(ID, expected);

                    ddb.updateItem(request);
```

For clarity, here is how I use the range key to find rows after a specific time.  If I remove this time range, then I would do a big scan every time to find rows after a specific time.

```
 Map keyConditions = new HashMap();

    AttributeValue attribute = new AttributeValue().withN("10");

    Condition hashKeyCondition = new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ.toString())
            .withAttributeValueList(attribute);

    keyConditions.put("hashKey", hashKeyCondition);

    // specify new records
    long lastQueryTime = PrefsActivity.getLastDynamoQueryTime(activity);
    String lastTimeString = String.valueOf(lastQueryTime);

    Log.v(TAG, "get Charts from dynamo that are after " + lastTimeString);

    // update the query time to now
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    PrefsActivity.setLastDynamoQueryTime(activity, now);

    AttributeValue timeAttribute = new AttributeValue().withN(lastTimeString);

    Condition timeCondition = new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.GT.toString())
            .withAttributeValueList(timeAttribute);

    keyConditions.put("problemRangeKey", timeCondition);


        List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> ChartsInMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, AttributeValue>>();

        Map lastEvaluatedKey = null;

        QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest().withTableName("tableName")
                    .withKeyConditions(keyConditions).withExclusiveStartKey(lastEvaluatedKey);

        QueryResult result = ddb.query(request);
```

I'm working with the latest AWS Android SDK. In the sample above, I'm setting the hashKey to "10". In practice, that will vary.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is, you want to update all items with a specific hashKey value and a specific column value (column name is id).

The table is Hash-Range schema. Since you don't know the range key, you have to fetch all the rows with that hashKey and then do a filter based on the column value (ID == value). You can use [query filter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html) to do that efficiently. Then for each row in your query, do a conditional put with expected value (ID == value) just to be sure.

```
QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest();
// set up query request (table name, etc)
// set up query filter (ID == value)

QueryResponse response = client.query(request)

for (item in response.items):
    PutItemRequest req = new PutItemRequest();
    // set up put item request
    // set up primary key for item to update
    //    hashkey = item.hashkey
    //    rangekey = item.rangeKey
    // set up expected value (ID == value)
    client.updateItem(req)
```

On the other hand, since you want to efficiently query all the rows after a specific time, you can create a [Local Secondary Index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html) with "time" as a range key instead of making "time" the range key of your base table. You can still do efficient query using LSI (compared with scanning the table and filter by time). Whats more important is, if your "ID" attribute can uniquely identify a row with your hashkey, you can make "ID" the range key of your base table. This way you can also update the item efficiently since you already know the hashkey value and range key value (id value).

Of course it only truly benefits you when your hashkey and "ID" can uniquely identify a row :)

Comment: Thanks - I created a local secondary index as you suggested. Works great!